# Is there a Windows command-line to list all files from my computer directory from 2015 for example?

Tags: windows, file, command-line, cmd

I need to list on cmd all files from 2015 of a directory and show the aumont size of it, how can I do that on command line? Im using Windows 7.

**Thank you**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
forfiles /d +01/01/2015 /p c:\ /s /c "cmd /c echo @fname @fdate
```

see

```
forfiles /?
```

To see size of folders in Documents, excluding music, video, or pictures folders.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Personal"') do set doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"^|findstr /l /v "Pictures Music Video"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Music.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Music"') do set Doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Pictures.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Pictures"') do set Doc=%A

for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders in Video.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Video"') do set Doc=%A
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders on the Desktop.

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Desktop"') do set doc=%A
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%doc%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders the Windows folder.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%windir%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

To see size of folders the Program Files folder.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %i IN (`dir "%ProgramFiles%" /a /s ^|findstr /i /v "\/"`) DO @echo %j&echo.
```

Comment: If you type `forfiles /?` you'll see the `@fsize` variable. As to the second it to find sizes of folders. It's unclear what exactly you are after (one folder, many folders etc)

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file will find all the files in a directory created in 2015 and show the total size of the matching files.

test.cmd

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _totalsize=0
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /a:-d /b`)  do (
   set _name=%%a
   set _date=%%~ta
   set _size=%%~za
   if /i "!_date:2015=!" NEQ "!_date!" (
     echo matched file !_name! with date !_date! and size !_size!
     set /a "_totalsize=_totalsize+_size"
   ) 
)
echo total size of matched files is !_totalsize!
```

Example output:

```
F:\projects>test
matched file countlines.cmd with date 23/03/2015 22:56 and size 277
matched file test.cmd with date 24/06/2015 00:24 and size 379
total size of matched files is 656

F:\projects>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `robocopy` to retrieve all the needed information

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"

    pushd "x:\where\the\files\are" && (

        rem Retrieve information 
        >"%tempFile%" (
            robocopy . . /l /nocopy /is /njh /ndl /np /ts /nc /maxage:20150101 /bytes
        )

        rem Show the file list
        findstr /r /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" "%tempFile%"

        rem Show full size
        for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr /r /i /c:"^ *bytes:" "%tempFile%"') do (
            echo(
            echo Total Size: %%a bytes
            echo(
        )

        rem Clean
        del /q "%tempFile%"
        popd
    )
```

Or, just from command line, from inside the folder to process

```
robocopy . . /l /nocopy /is /njh /ndl /np /ts /nc /maxage:20150101 /bytes
```